# c# - Group by and having with two counts in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, having

How can I write the follow query with Linq in C#?

```
SELECT MAX(A2.LINHA_PLANILHA)
FROM MD_IMP_FORCA_VENDA_DADOS_A2 A2
WHERE A2.LINHA <> '0' 
    AND TRIM(A2.SETORES) IS NOT NULL
    AND A2.LINHA_PLANILHA <> 1
    AND USUARIO = V_USUARIO
GROUP BY A2.LINHA, A2.BRICK
HAVING COUNT(A2.BRICK) > 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT A2.SETORES) > 1;
```

I thought to do this:

```
var result = from r in dataTable.AsEnumerable() 
where r.Field<string>(1) != "0" 
    && r.Field<string>(2).Trim() != null 
    && r.Field<Int32>(0) != 1 
group r by new {Linha = r.Field<string>(1), Brick = r.Field<string>(3) } into temp 
where temp.Count() > 1 
select new { MaxLinha = (from r2 in temp select r2.Field<Int32>(0)).Max()};
```

But I don't know how to put the two COUNTS of HAVING clause in Linq query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Zago

Comment: One question: What did you try?

Comment: @Thomas is asking if you've actually tried any LINQ expressions yourself? Typically this forum is for asking help with why particular code is not working.

Comment: Sorry about my confusion and my mistake...I edited my post with what I'm thinking to do.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
var query = db.MD_IMP_FORCA_VENDA_DADOS_A2
    .Where(x => x.LINHA  != "0" 
             && x.SETORES != null 
             && x.SETORES.Trim() != ""
             && x.LINHA_PLANILHA <> 1
             && x.USUARIO = x.V_USUARIO
    ) 
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.LINHA, x.BRICK })
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1 && g.Select(x => x.SETORES).Distinct().Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Max(x => x.LINHA_PLANILHA));
```